# Python error: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

so I'm working on a save profile feature and I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error:

```
__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

This is the function it happens in (right after it hits the `self.profiles.update line`):

```
@view_config(route_name="profile", request_method='POST')
def save_profile(self):
    try:
        json = self.request.json_body
        #username = str(json['userName'])
        first_name = str(json['firstName'])
        last_name = str(json['lastName'])
        phones = str(json['phones'])
        emails = str(json['emails'])
        self.profiles.update(self, firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name, emails=emails, phones=phones)
        value = {'result:': 'success', 'message': 'Profile Saved!'}
        self.respond(value)
        return self.route('profile')
    except Exception, err:
        print err
        value = {'result:': 'error', 'message': 'There was an error processing the request'}
        self.respond(value)
        return self.route('profile')
```

[image]

The expanded console:

[image]

I did a project wide search for *init* and this seems like the only function that matches

```
class WhoView(Extension):
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.session = request.session
        self.request = request
        self.status_code = 200
        self.content_type = "text/html"
        ctx = self.session.ctx
        self.request_context = context

        Extension.__init__(self, ctx)

    def attach_session(self, token):
        self.ctx.attach_session(token)
```

Any thoughts? Additional info you need to see?

Comment: This doesn't resolve your issue, but note that every object that is created in your program calls `__init__` -- it's the method used to initialize a (mutable) object.

Comment: The full stack trace would be quite useful. If you have to catch the exception instead of just letting it propagate, you can use `sys.exc_info()[2]` to get the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not redirecting anywhere (self.route does a redirect).  Also, you can't redirect here because you're doing an ajax call.  I'm pretty sure the assignment for phones and emails isn't correct because you're casting arrays to strings.  We'll talk about it in the office tomorrow.  Also as sza pointed out, you don't pass self for method calls.

```
@view_config(route_name="profile", request_method='POST')
def save_profile(self):
    try:
        json = self.request.json_body
        #username = str(json['userName'])
        first_name = str(json['firstName'])
        last_name = str(json['lastName'])
        phones = str(json['phones'])
        emails = str(json['emails'])
        self.profiles.update(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name, emails=emails, phones=phones)
        value = {'result:': 'success', 'message': 'Profile Saved!'}
    except Exception, err:
        print err
        value = {'result:': 'error', 'message': 'There was an error processing the request'}

    #returns a json response
    return self.respond(value)
```

Comment: Sweet! In the end had to also remove str from the phones and emails arrays

Comment: Ya, Leon is sitting about 2 feet behind me

Answer (score 1):

Isn't

```
self.profiles.update(self, firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name, emails=emails, phones=phones)
```

should be

```
self.profiles.update(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name, emails=emails, phones=phones)
```

Comment: yeah I shouldn't have put self inside